# Why should I have to rebuild index which is having less than Avg. fragmentation is less than 1% to get performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-performance

Why should I have to rebuild index which is having less than Avg. fragmentation is less than 1% to get performance?

I have a table which used to update frequently,but when I see in depth and check for avg. fragmentation,which is used to less than 1 % even. When I rebuild that index, automatically performance has been improved.

I have joined this table with more than 2 tables in single query.

I want to know as per MSDN we should not do anything to less than 1% index containing table, but without rebuilding my query is not giving me result faster. I have also set FillFactor= 75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragmentation rarely affects performance much.  Rebuilding an index *also* updates the statistics associated with the index and invalidates the cached plans associated with the object.

Comment: I am partially agree with you, but there may be affect of Fragmentation as my understanding by reading [MSDN blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes).  If there is a rare affect in performance as per your feedback, why my query become faster  after rebuilding clustered index of my table!!!

Comment: "my query become faster after rebuilding clustered index " the updated statistics is the most likely cause, but the updated query plans could do that too.

Comment: Thanks David for your view which gave me a way to think on another aspects/way, as per your feedback, I have re-analyse whole query and execution plan and I thought I should add missing non clustered index on that table and finally I found that my query ran faster as compared to previous execution. I know that it is bad habit to add non clustered indexes for all queries which are slow in terms of execution.